# Can you read an updated mtime, but when reading the contents they have yet to be updated?

Tags: linux, files, ext4, timestamps, concurrency

Assuming `touch` etc. is not involved, just standard `open`, `write`, `close`, `link` system calls.

One process is updating files, another is periodically `stat`ing to see if they've changed and reloading the contents.
If it possible for the second process to end up with an incorrect view of a file, if it reloaded before the first had completed the write?

Looking primarily at Linux ext4 file-systems, but information for others could be useful if they differ.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX requires that read-after-write() always return the correct data, according to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/write.html :

> After a write() to a regular file has successfully returned:
>
> - Any successful read() from each byte position in the file that
>       was modified by that write will return the data specified by
>       the write() for that position until such byte positions are
>       again modified.

The file mtime is not updated until the end of the write in Linux, so it *shouldn't* be possible to see an updated mtime without seeing the data that caused *that* mtime update.

> Upon successful completion, where nbyte is greater than 0, write() will mark for update the st_ctime and st_mtime fields of the file

Ext4 tries to ensure POSIX-compliance, so you should be safe in this case, but not every filesystem is fully POSIX compliant, so YMMV.

Comment: That specification (and for `fsync`) don't say anything about when the mtime is actually updated and visible to other processes. The key appears to be "as defined for synchronised I/O file integrity completion", but I don't see where that's actually defined.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what granularity you want. Single `write()` calls should be atomic (*). But if the application does multiple write calls as part of a single logical operation, the other process might wake up in the middle to read only part of it.

*) The system call can return after writing only a part of the data, this will be indicated in the return value. But I don't know if that can happen on local files on Linux.

Consider this sequence:

```
--task 1--                  --task 2--
write()                     ..  
..                          stat()
..                          read()
write()
```

If the two writes on the left are part of a single logical modification, task 2 just read only a part of that modification.

Comment: But in that case does every write (or flush) update the mtime, therefore the second will get it on the next check?

Comment: It should, but I'm not sure how accurate the timestamps are in practice. It may depend on the programming language / environment too: e.g. Perl's default stat only gives a granularity of a full second.